# Python3 - output specific line of my run result to a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running this script below (https://github.com/vikas027/docker-gitlab-api). The script works properly and the result is seen in my terminal. My goal now is to output ONLY `token` to a `.txt file` as opposed to the whole result. The token is being generated automatically. It's always given on the very last line and it's a random string as a side note.

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Script that creates Personal Access Token for Gitlab API;
Tested with:
- Gitlab Community Edition 10.1.4
- Gitlab Enterprise Edition 12.6.2
- Gitlab Enterprise Edition 13.4.4
- GitLab Enterprise Edition 13.12.3
Example: ./<script> <name-of-token> <expiry>
./<script> mytoken 2022-08-27
## Requirements :-
1) Python3
2) Sript needs below environment variables to be setup:
  - GITLAB_ADMIN_USER='root'
  - GITLAB_ADMIN_PASSWD='5iveL!fe'
"""

# Import Modules
import sys
import requests
import os
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Variables
endpoint = os.environ['GITLAB_URL']
root_route = urljoin(endpoint, "/")
sign_in_route = urljoin(endpoint, "/users/sign_in")
pat_route = urljoin(endpoint, "/-/profile/personal_access_tokens")

login = os.environ['GITLAB_ADMIN_USER']
password = os.environ['GITLAB_ADMIN_PASSWD']

# Methods
def find_csrf_token(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
    token = soup.find(attrs={"name": "csrf-token"})
    param = soup.find(attrs={"name": "csrf-param"})
    data = {param.get("content"): token.get("content")}
    return data


def obtain_csrf_token():
    r = requests.get(root_route)
    token = find_csrf_token(r.text)
    return token, r.cookies


def obtain_authenticity_token(cookies):
    r = requests.get(pat_route, cookies=cookies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    token = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'authenticity_token', 'type': 'hidden'}).get('value')
    return token


def sign_in(csrf, cookies):
    data = {
        "user[login]": login,
        "user[password]": password,
        "user[remember_me]": 0,
        "utf8": "✓"
    }
    data.update(csrf)
    r = requests.post(sign_in_route, data=data, cookies=cookies)
    token = find_csrf_token(r.text)
    return token, r.history[0].cookies


def obtain_personal_access_token(name, expires_at, csrf, cookies, authenticity_token):
    data = {
        "personal_access_token[expires_at]": expires_at,
        "personal_access_token[name]": name,
        "personal_access_token[scopes][]": "api",
        "authenticity_token": authenticity_token,
        "utf8": "✓"
    }
    data.update(csrf)
    r = requests.post(pat_route, data=data, cookies=cookies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    token = soup.find('input', id='created-personal-access-token').get('value')
    return token


def main():
    csrf1, cookies1 = obtain_csrf_token()
    print("root", csrf1, cookies1)
    csrf2, cookies2 = sign_in(csrf1, cookies1)
    print("sign_in", csrf2, cookies2)
    authenticity_token = obtain_authenticity_token(cookies2)

    name = sys.argv[1] 
    expires_at = sys.argv[2] 
    token = obtain_personal_access_token(name, expires_at, csrf2, cookies2, authenticity_token)
    print(token)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the command I run to output to the `.txt` `python3 token.py test never>output.txt` and below is the result when you cat the `.txt` file:

```
root {'authenticity_token': 'xxxx........+=='} <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie _gitlab_session=1db0c99647496bfea26d1a6d6ba35a0b for gitlab.xx-xxx.xxx.com/>]>
sign_in {'authenticity_token': 'yppRFqghB+ZTjm0HPLxa3G6bimoK/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx....=='} <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie _gitlab_session=232a41b853887b654e5cd86ce129cff7 for gitlab.xx-xxx.xxx.com/>, <Cookie known_sign_in=%3D%3D-- for gitlab.xx-xxx.xxx.com/>]>
token
```

In other word I would like to output the 3rd only line to the `.txt` which is `token`
Thank you I will appreciate any feedback.

Comment: You can either use `| tail -n 1 > output.txt` or write the file with your script instead of your shell

Comment: can you remove the print statements for root / sign_in ?  sending stdout of the script to output.txt is going to write all print statements unless you do somethin glike LinFelix suggested.
 
Another option would be to write token to a file doing something like 
`with open('token.txt',w) as f: f.write(token)`

Comment: @Alex thanks for the pointers it worked :)

Comment: great--no problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to remove those two lines from the script to just get the token output:

```
#    print("root", csrf1, cookies1) test 2
    csrf2, cookies2 = sign_in(csrf1, cookies1)
#    print("sign_in", csrf2, cookies2) test 1
```

@Alex thanks for the pointers. Really helpful.